# How to get a Office formatted table into Mailto

Tags: html, mailto

I fear this may be a stright no, I have a requirement for a button on a website to open a mailto with an email populated with a table in the body that will work like an office table. (i.e. if I tab through it creates a new line)

(I have an alternative of an excel sheet download with instructions to email when complete, however the powers that be want less steps.)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you already tried and what is not working.

Comment: That would be pointless its a question on whether a piece of functionality is even possible. It would not add to the request, it would infact detract from the question.